# jQuery UI's Sortable's connectWith fails with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, html-lists, jquery-ui-sortable

Moving a `li` element into a `ul` HTML list with jQuery UI Sortable does not work with jQuery Mobile (dragging works, but the `ul` does not accept the `li` element). If you comment the line where jQuery Mobile is imported, it will work. If you un-comment it again, it will stop working. But I need jQuery Mobile for my project. Furthermore, the shape of the element being dragged changes as you lift it (Firefox 29).

You can find a screenshot of the HTML file [here](http://pasteboard.co/O30qy86.png).

*Context:* I'm working on a hybrid / web app using jQuery Mobile. It's an educational app and in one exercise type, the user has to drag some terms into the right list but placing the term in the list doesn't work because the list doesn't accept the new `li` tag. I simplified the scenario so that there is only one term to move into one list.

```
<html>  
  <head>  
<title>jQueryUI Sortables</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- remove this line and the example will work (Firefox) -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- but I need jQuery Mobile in my project! -->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(function() {  
    $("#part_0").sortable({  
      connectWith: "#col_0"  
    });  
    $("#col_0").sortable({  
      connectWith: "#part_0"  
    });  
  });  
</script> 
<style>
li { margin: 0px; padding: 10px; float:left; border-radius: 5px; }
.smallList {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 0px;}
.bigList {width: 100%; height: 100%; list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 0px;}
.part {margin: 0px; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: Orange; color: White;}
</style>    
</head>  
<body>  
<ul id="part_0" class="smallList">  
  <li class="part">Drag this</li> 
</ul><br /><br /><br /><br />
<ul id="col_0" class="bigList">  
  <li class="part">Into</li>  
  <li class="part">This</li>  
  <li class="part">List</li>  
</ul>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something demonstrating the issue..?

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YCL3x/), but for some reason, it is working there. If you put the code I posted directly into an HTML file without jsfiddle, it won't work with Firefox. But I found a workaround, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trying, I finally found a work-around. I don't know why, but with jQuery Mobile, you need to set the `ul` tag to `float: left` which is not necessary, if you use jQuery UI without jQuery Mobile. I don't think it's obvious, but adding this single line into the CSS makes the dragging work again:

```
<style>
/* BEGIN INSERTION: */
ul { float: left; }
/* END INSERTION */

li { margin: 0px; padding: 10px; float:left; border-radius: 5px; }
.smallList {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 0px;}
.bigList {width: 100%; height: 100%; list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 0px;}
.part {margin: 0px; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: Orange; color: White;}
</style>
```